# How to merge raster with FME with different spatial resulution?

Tags: raster, fme-form, merge

I have two sets of raster (tiff, aerial photos) which I want to merge to one raster file with FME.
The two sets have different spatial resolutions. Set A has a better resolution as B. The two set do overlap.
How can I merge these raster with FME? Requirements:

1. Use Resolution (size of pixel) from set A
2. Where the raster do overlap: use pixels from set A
3. Optional requirement: Position of pixels from set A should not change (nor resampling of A. only resampling of B)

Example with 4 raster files from set A (blue) and 4 raster files from set B (red).

[image]

I tried to use FMEs RasterMosaiker and set the order in Navigator but I can not meet requirement 1 and 2 simultaneously:

- first A then B: I loss requirement 2
- first B then A: I loss
  requirement 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't do a lot of raster work with FME so this might not be entirely correct, but these are the general steps I would use:

1. Use a **[RasterResampler](https://www.safe.com/transformers/raster-resampler/)** to change the Cell Sizing of Raster B.  You could extract this from Raster A first and feed it into the X/Y spacing. Or, just type it in manually if you know it.

   [image]
2. Feed the results of the above along with Raster A into a **[RasterMosaicker](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/rastermosaicker.htm?Highlight=rastermosaicker)**.
3. You could also have a look at the **[RasterExpressionEvaluator](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/rasterexpressionevaluator.htm)** which can do conditional statements where the two rasters overlap.